# Использование слова "сенсибилизация"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"В начале каждой части книги ... дано введение, задачей которого является  сенсибилизация  к восприятию содержания учебника, пробуждение интереса к тому, что будет происходить на уроках".
Уместно ли  в  данном контексте слово сенсибилизация?

Answer (score 1):

Вас что интересует? Само слово или предложение, в котором оно используется?
Слово-то такое словарями фиксируется, но я крепко сомневаюсь, что здесь оно использовано корректно. Сензибилизатор - вещество, а не какое-то там "введение".